# Yii + ZendService/LiveDocx

Tags: yii, livedocx

I am trying to use the Zend Service Livedocx. I am using two models in my application - Submission and SubmissionFiles. I am saving the Submission data and the SubmissionFiles data with the Create action in the SubmissionController. I am trying to call the MailMerge class in that action but I am getting the error: **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ZendService\LiveDocx\AbstractLiveDocx in C:\wamp\www\publications\src\web\protected\vendors\ZendService\LiveDocx\AbstractLiveDocx.php**

## SubmissionController

//some code

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Submission;

    if(isset($_POST['Submission']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Submission'];
        if($model->save()) 
        {
            $modelFile = new SubmissionFiles;
            if(isset($_POST['SubmissionFiles']))
            {   
            Yii::import('application.vendors.zendservice.livedocx.*');

                $phpLiveDocx = new MailMerge(); 
 //somecode
```

## protected/vendors/ZendService/LiveDocx/MailMerge.php

```
<?php

require_once 'ZendService\LiveDocx\AbstractLiveDocx.php';

class MailMerge extends AbstractLiveDocx
{ //somecode
```

## protected/vendors/ZendService/LiveDocx/AbstractLiveDocx.php

```
<?php

namespace ZendService\LiveDocx;

use Traversable;
use Zend\Soap\Client as SoapClient;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;

abstract class AbstractLiveDocx
{ //some code
```

If I comment the require_once 'ZendService\LiveDocx\AbstractLiveDocx.php'; in MailMerge.php,
I get the error:
**Fatal error: Class 'AbstractLiveDocx' not found in C:\wamp\www\publications\src\web\protected\vendors\ZendService\LiveDocx\MailMerge.php**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using composer to include Zend as dependancy. If so you must add the autoloader to your index.php file(or whatever you bootstrap with).

```
// change the following paths if necessary
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php');
```

After that replace the require_once line with:

```
use ZendService\LiveDocx\AbstractLiveDocx;
```

Hope that works :)

Comment: I read that I can just paste the zendservice folder in vendors and then use the class with  **Yii::import('application.vendors.zendservice.livedocx.*');**.
I don't have an autoloader file.

Comment: I really recommend using composer and its autoloader since this file may require other dependencies that will result in this error.

Comment: Okay, I downloaded yiiframework.com/extension/zendautoloader and included require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/extensions/zend-autoloader-component/E‌​ZendAutoloader.php'); in the index.php, but now I get **include(MailMerge.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory **.. The service is placed in protected/vendors/zend/zendservice/livedocx as said in the documentation.. any ideas?

Comment: No, don't use this. Download composer. After that go to your protected folder (delete the vendor folder if you have only zend there) and type composer require "zendframework/zendservice-livedocx": "2.0.*@dev". This will create vendor folder and autoloader.php inside it. Proceed with my response above.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the dumb questions but I'm really getting lost. Is this **https://getcomposer.org/download/** what I need and if yes how do I use that .phar file?

Comment: Sry I'm on windows and it only works by typing composer. If you are linux and have a phar file the use it like this:  php composer.phar .....

Comment: Ok, I'm dumb :D. I am also on windows and after the installation I use the command you provided and I get this:
**Please provide a version constraint for the 2.0.*@dev requirement:**

Comment: I have a typo the command is :  composer require "zendframework/zendservice-livedocx":"2.0.*@dev"

Comment: I have done everything you said, the vendor folder is generated, i changed the bootstrap index.php and still i get: **include(MailMerge.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

Comment: try this :  new ZendService\LiveDocx\MailMerge